# Custom query var rewriting with only variable

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, query-variable

On every post there is a "read" (default) and "listen" button that users can click on without page refresh.

The listen tab can be accessed directly through

```
domain.com/category/post-title/?listen=listen
```

and

```
domain.com/category/post-title/listen/listen
```

I would like to edit the rewrite rule so that the same page can accessed though

```
domain.com/category/post-title/listen
```

How would I go about doing this?

My code:

```
function cp_narrations_query_vars( $qvars ) {
  $qvars[] = 'listen';
  return $qvars;
} add_filter( 'query_vars', 'cp_narrations_query_vars' , 10, 1 );

function cp_add_my_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'listen', EP_PERMALINK );
} add_action( 'init', 'cp_add_my_endpoint' );
```

Comment: you should already be able to do that with the code you have here, you just have to check if the `listen` query var exists rather than if it equals listen.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Should've thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered thanks to Milo's comment.

I wrote a small function to check if the query variable exists. Note that `get_query_var('listen')` didn't work for me.

```
function is_listen() {    
    $vars = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars;

    if ( array_key_exists('listen', $vars) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Use it in a conditional like so:

```
if ( is_listen() ) {
    // Display listen tab
}
```